# XFS over iSCSI share with cluster; will fencing cause data corruption/loss?

Tags: cluster, xfs, iscsi, high-availability

When using XFS on iSCSI share, where HA is enabled, nodes may be fenced by cluster. Will this result in data loss / corruption / etc. ?

Comment: who's cluster ? suse ? redhat/centos ?